# Xcode: How to embed a framework with "Code Sign on Copy" using CMake?

Tags: xcode, cmake, frameworks, codesign

## Background

I'm trying to embed a framework to an Xcode project through CMake, the framework is unsigned which means it needs "Code Sign On Copy".

The CMake command I'm using is

```
set_source_files_properties(${SOME_FRAMEWORK} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Frameworks)
```

This does the trick to put framework in "Copy Files" (under "Build Phases"), but "Code Sign On Copy" remain unchecked.

## Questions

1. Is there a way to set "Code Sign On Copy" through CMake?
2. It's possible to execute a PRE_LINK command which `codesign` the framework, problem is the identity is mine and I couldn't share it with others. Is there a good way to retrieve the default identity that Xcode is using?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_library(MyFramework ...)
```

set_source_files_properties(MyFramework
PROPERTIES
XCODE_REMOVE_HEADERS_ON_COPY ON
XCODE_CODE_SIGN_ON_COPY ON)

add_executable(MyApp MACOSX_BUNDLE ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(MyApp PROPERTIES
XCODE_EMBED_FRAMEWORKS
MyFramework.framework)
target_link_libraries(MyApp MyFramework)

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/2089

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is using `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to patch `project.pbxproj` after CMake generates Xcode project.

To be specific, I need to look for framework object ID in `project.pbxproj`, then add "CodeSignOnCopy" attribute to it.

PlistBuddy: https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/PlistBuddy/

Answer (score 0):

To enable `CodeSignOnCopy` you can manually add the attribute to the source file:

```
set_source_files_properties(${SOME_FRAMEWORK} 
  PROPERTIES 
    MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Frameworks
    XCODE_FILE_ATTRIBUTES "CodeSignOnCopy"
)
```

Regarding the identity: Usually "Apple Development" works fine, but you can also make it a CMake cache variable so that in the rare case where someone needs to use a different identity they can overwrite it. To do that use

```
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "Apple Development" CACHE STRING "")
```

in the CMakeLists.txt of the project, and overwrite it from the command line, either by adding `-DCMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="<other-id>"` when first configuring the project, or by using

```
cmake -DCMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="<other-id>" <build-dir>
```

with an already existing build directory.